# How to pass parameters from batch file to the array in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, batch-file

I am new in Perl. Could you please give me advice to pass parameters from batch file to the array in Perl? Or is it possible?

Batch file:

```
@echo off
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe D:\perl\prog.pl a 30 5 d o 78 g
```

and read these parameters from the array in Perl script and print on the screen:

```
($st, $st2, $com, $ep, $co, $vel, $sig) = @_;

print @_;
```

Comment: You can use %1 .. %n parameters

Comment: `@_` is for a sub's parameters. The script's parameters are found in `@ARGV`

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

> `Sample.bat` Batch File contents:

`perl -w d:\testing\SampleScript.pl %1 %2 %3`

> `SampleScript.pl` Script contents:

```
my ($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) = @ARGV;

print "First Param... $arg1\n";

print "Second Param... $arg2\n";

print "Third Param... $arg3\n";
```

> On your Prompt:

`$: Sample.bat Parrot Pigeon Duck`

Thanks